# Steps for installing new GDAL version for Python in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gdal, ubuntu, proj, geos, ubuntugis

If I'm installing the GDAL stock version from Ubuntu 18.04 then the installed version is 2.2 and I need at least 3.0.4 to better handle Sentinel 2 data. Is there  a way to update GDAL to version 3.1.0?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Conda for this intent as 3.1 is available

```
conda search gdal --channel conda-forge
```

The recipe can be the following

```bsh
conda create --name gdal_31 python=3.6
conda activate gdal_31
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install gdal libgdal
gdalinfo --version # Confirm GDAL command line version
python -c "import osgeo.gdal;print(osgeo.gdal.__version__)"
3.1.2 # Confirm "right" GDAL in Python
# Do your stuff here e.g running Python scripts using GDAL or command line

conda deactivate # Go away from the virtualenv when finished
```

Answer (score 0):

For commandline use of gdal you could use available docker images from https://hub.docker.com/r/osgeo/gdal/tags.